# Comma-first JS formatter

Tags: javascript, coding-style, formatting

Do you know of a JS formatter that will support the [comma-first](https://gist.github.com/357981) coding style?

```
var a = 'ape'
  , b = 'bat'
  , c = 'cat'
  , d = 'dog'
  , e = 'elf'
  , f = 'fly'
  , g = 'gnu'
  , h = 'hat'
  , i = 'ibu'
  ;
```

So far, I've looked at [JS Beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) & [SourceFormatX](http://www.sourceformat.com/) but couldn't find an option for it.

Comment: Thought it might be useful to know, I'm not sure this question is a valid question in Stack Overflow.

Comment: @gdoron yeah, I was thinking about putting it on Programmers but it doesn't seem to belong there either. Know of a better place?

Comment: No, Propose new site at Area 51, _"off-topic"_. I have some questions to ask there too... `:)`

Comment: This feature is now available on the official [JS Beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) project.  No hacking required.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I modified the jsbeautifier code a little here:

http://jsfiddle.net/RabTN/29/

press `doit` to see the beautified code.

I specifically modified line 1080:

```
        if (flags.var_line) {
            if (token_text === ',') {
                if (flags.var_line_tainted) {
                    flags.var_line_reindented = true;
                    flags.var_line_tainted = false;
                    print_newline();
                    print_token();
                    print_single_space();
                    break;
                } else {
```

and line 1123

```
        if (token_text === ',') {
            if (flags.var_line) {
                if (flags.var_line_tainted) {
                    print_newline();
                    print_token();
                    print_single_space();

                    flags.var_line_tainted = false;
                } else {
                    print_newline();
                    print_token();
                    print_single_space();
                }
            } else if (last_type === 'TK_END_BLOCK' && flags.mode !== "(EXPRESSION)") {
                print_token();
                if (flags.mode === 'OBJECT' && last_text === '}') {
                    print_newline();
                } else {
                    print_single_space();
                }
            } else {
                if (flags.mode === 'OBJECT') {
                    print_newline();
                    print_token();
                    print_single_space();
                } else {
                    // EXPR or DO_BLOCK
                    print_token();
                    print_single_space();
                }
            }
            break
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I needed. Btw, you should definitely submit this as a patch to https://github.com/einars/js-beautify; I'm sure more than a few people will find an option like this very useful.