# Objective reasons against leading commas in Javascript

Tags: javascript, coding-style

I recently joined a project where leading commas are used as a standard.

While I understand the reason of this style (safe commenting of lines), It's very inconvenient (To put it mildly).

I have a strong feeling that it's not only about taste, and I need better reasons than 'I don't like it' to convince the team not to use this style.

p.s. Sample code:

```
function cls(){

    var prop = {
         a:'a'
        ,b:'b'
        ,c:'c'
        ,d:'d'
    };

    var arr = [
         11
        ,12
        ,13
        ,14
    ];

    var  x=1
        ,y=2
        ,z=3;

    return {

        f:function(){       
            alert(prop.a);      
        }

        , g:function(){
            alert(arr[0]);
        }

        , h: function(){
            alert(x);
        }

    };
}    


var test = cls();
test.f();test.g();test.h();
```

Objective reasons so far (Partially from the answers and partially mine):

1. This style is very uncommon, and particularly in the JavaScript learning material and frameworks. It's very likely that newcomers to the project will feel uncomfortable , as well as developers that need to deal with projects formatted differently
2. Most auto-formatting tools in IDEs don't respect this style (not by default nor via configuration)
3. Potential bugs in various tools/utilities, because this tools are most likely implemented and tested on a regularly placed commas. Example: Sencha CMD has bugs when compiling JavaScript code with leading commas

Update:
We did auto-formatted all the project according to the common style (Specifically, according to google style guide: http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml). 
The code looks significantly better, and all the tools works as expected (IDE, Optimizers, Builders (Sencha CMD), Syntax validator, ...).
It's a large project within large company, so it wasn't a trivial decision. Also, it cost a loss of clear CVS history - but eventually it was worth it.

Comment: the properties of an object are no longer aligned

Comment: They actually put one or two spaces before the first item to keep it aligned ( fixing the example now )

Comment: It just looks ugly that's all, `,` looks like a unary operator for the variable, but really it's not. You might as well put `+`, `-`, `*`, `/` in front as well, if you put commas in front.

Comment: it is loosing code-readability.

Comment: Not saying this is a bad question, but I feel answers to this question will mostly be opinion based.

Comment: That's why I asked for a convincing , objective reasons. Now all I have is my opinion-based argument that it's ugly ( which doesn't helped me unfortunately.. )

Comment: Get them to use tabs, because tabs are better, and get them to not declare multiple variables in the same line, so it won’t matter.

Comment: I have been using this style for over 10 years and migrated to it for quite a few reasons. I personally find it more readable and its use is getting more and more common in JavaScript. Look at the bigger node.js developers and there are a few notables that use it all the time. It does cause some problems with some IDE's like IntelliJ though.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see how this is supposed to make for safer commenting of lines. Sure, if you comment the last item you avoid the trailing comma, but if you comment the first item you get a leading comma. Middle items you're safe either way.

If you use trailing commas throughout, you can comment the first item without getting a leading comma, but commenting the last item will leave a trailing comma.

The difference being that trailing commas are generally accepted in js object literals, while leading commas are not.

Comment: First-comma in object is easier to notice than last. still I don't think this single reason justifies this style

Answer (score 5):

I think it's OK. Will lead you less typo-error when you want to add something or delete something.

Update one line is OK not need to add comma or delete comma for other lines.

```
var prop = {
    a: 'a'
  , b: 'b'
  , c: 'c'
  , d: 'd'
}

var arr = [
    11
  , 12
  , 13
  , 14
]

var x=1
  , y=2
  , z=3
```

It's a default code style of [Haskell](https://github.com/tibbe/haskell-style-guide/blob/master/haskell-style.md)

Command-first you will never miss a comma, see [here](https://gist.github.com/isaacs/357981)

Comment: I think the way you have done it here, with aligned variable names and some spaces, is much clearer. I like this whilst I dislike the OP's style.

Comment: Actually in Haskell you would have something equivalent to `var prop =\n  { a: 'a'\n  , b: '...'\n  , c:...\n  }`, which is much nicer IMHO because of the symmetry of aligned "special" characters (opening/closing braces and commas).

Answer (score 3):

If you really hate the style, just code normally:

```
function cls() {
    var prop = {
        a: 'a',
        b: 'b',
        c: 'c',
        d: 'd'
    };

    var arr = [
        11, 12, 13, 14
    ];

    var x = 1,
        y = 2,
        z = 3;

    return {

        f: function () {
            alert(prop.a);
        },
        g: function () {
            alert(arr[0]);
        },
        h: function () {
            alert(x);
        }

    };
}

var test = cls();
test.f();
test.g();
test.h();
```

Then plug it into a [formatter](http://jsfiddle.net/RabTN/29/) that changes the style. ([Original Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872184/comma-first-js-formatter))

Then it looks like this:

```
function cls() {
    var prop = {
        a: 'a'
        , b: 'b'
        , c: 'c'
        , d: 'd'
    };

    var arr = [
    11, 12, 13, 14];

    var x = 1
        , y = 2
        , z = 3;

    return {

        f: function() {
            alert(prop.a);
        },
        g: function() {
            alert(arr[0]);
        },
        h: function() {
            alert(x);
        }

    };
}

var test = cls();
test.f();
test.g();
test.h();
```

Comment: Good idea , will work for the 'cick-start' files , but formatting existing code will wreak havoc to the CVS

Comment: Formatting working code in a good formatter will never break code. Does this break the code for you?

Comment: I believe that should only be once, and code should always be properly formatted anyway. In the revisions you'll just see a lot of spaces added or removed.

Comment: I agree. It's a good thing to do as last resort. but I hope to resolve it "from the root"

Answer (score 2):

This format does result in *clearer diffs*, since additions to the list or dictionary or declarations don't affect the lines containing existing elements.

Still, I prefer this sane format (which works in all modern browsers and even some old ones):

```
{
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2,
    baz: 3,
}

[
    'foo',
    'bar',
    'baz',
]
```

Comment: FTR: not all javascript engines will accept trailing commas.

Comment: True. However even most of the old browsers do, including Firefox 1 and IE 9. The ones that do not are IE 6, 7, and 8. If you're using those you're probably transpiling…